# Exporting enums in Angular modules

Tags: javascript, angular, enums, typescript2.0, angular-module

Does anyone know if it’s possible to export enums in Angular modules?
If not, are there any best practises to ship enums within Angular modules?

```
// not working example
// i dont know how to export GreatEnum

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GreatComponent } from './great.component';
import { GreatEnum } from './great.enum';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule       
    ],
    declarations: [GreatComponent ],
    exports: [GreatComponent ]
})
export class GreatModule {
}
```

Comment: show your enum file

Comment: Like classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245869/5468463

Comment: What do you think you need to export? Why would you want to inject it using DI?

Comment: you can directly use them when you are using `index.ts` barrel file

Comment: The enum file looks just like:

export enum GreatEnum { 'foo' = 1, 'bar' = 2 }

Comment: In case you are looking how to use enums from a subcompent into the parents component - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923744/pass-enums-in-angular2-view-templates/35924445

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why you need to export `enum` from the `modules`?. It is not necessary . It is like an `interfaces` and `classes`. You can use it everywhere, except directly in the `templates`.

You can just import them in any file which you want and use there. For them there is no error like

> Directive or Component is not found

Comment: I'm writing modules for reusing them in several angular apps. Thats why I want to ship enums within the module.

Comment: Look. When you will add your modules in the packages of an application, you can export it from the `barrel` file of your package. It may contains for example `export yourModule from yourFile; export yourEnum from yourEnumFile` and then get your module and enum like
`import { YourModule, YourEnum } from YourPackage;`

Answer (score 10):

If you are writing libraries, you have to export enums with the keyword const

```
export const enum <ENUM_NAME>
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once...